# Using a package from packages.config in C++ visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, onnxruntime

I am developing a code in C++ using as IDEE Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows 10 workstation. I need the `onnxruntime` library, so I have installed it by the NuGet package menager. The installation went ok and in my solution I have a folder `Resource files` and within it I have the file `packages.config`. Its content is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <packages>
     <package id="Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime" version="1.12.1" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

My `main.cpp` is quite simple. It is a simple `hello world` where I try to use the installed package. But when I compile, it gives me an error on the  `using Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime;` directive. I have followed the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/overview-and-workflow.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello world\n"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime` is a .NET package

Comment: In the guide at https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/install/ it says that it can be used for C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnnxRuntime lib and dll can be found in folder `Yourproject\packages\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.XXX\runtimes\win-x64\native`.Header file folder `XXX\packages\Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.XXX\build\native\include`
Try adding them as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That package is for .NET C#. You are trying to use a .NET package with C++ (which you can't)

Perhaps consider switching to C#?

Comment: Ehm, no. I have followed the guide specific for C++ here https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/install/

Comment: Could you follow this video guide? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imjqRdsm2Qw